# How many Retrofit Interceptors can I add to a Retrofit instance?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

One of my interview questions I had was: 
What is the maximum number of interceptors I can add to a Retrofit instance?

I took a minute to think, if I'm creating such a library, why do I limit the number of interceptors unless it consumes too much resources, so my answer was I think there is no limit but I should be careful to not leak memory.

I'm interested to hear some of your answers to learn more.

I have done my search to learn about this, but I did not find a good answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

You’re limited by the runtime’s stack size. Probably something between 100 and 1000 before it fails with a StackOverflowError.

Comment: Could you further explain why that is the case? I know that you will get a StackOverflowError when you are exceeding a limit of calling methods within methods (e.g. recursion). But with Interceptors, there is one Interceptor applied after each other from my understanding, so why does it affect the runtime stack?

Comment: All interceptors are on the stack simultaneously when the ultimate network transmissions are made.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a trick question.
interceptors are added to the `okhttpClient`, not the retrofit instance directly.

---

Your answer however seems correct:

```
// OkHttpClient.kt > Builder

internal val interceptors: MutableList<Interceptor> = mutableListOf()

fun addInterceptor(interceptor: Interceptor) = apply {
  interceptors += interceptor
}
```

---

```
// OkHttpClient.kt > OkHttpClient

@get:JvmName("interceptors") val interceptors: List<Interceptor> =
    builder.interceptors.toImmutableList()
```

---

Same behaviour for the `networkInterceptors`